# New window as background process

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, multithreading

I have a grid with linkbutton to open row details in new window. Loading new window takes about 2 minutes. So is there a way to make this load new window as background process and let user continue browse in main context. Any help is appreciated.

I tried following approach and though the main page is available for user input, click on any other link does not do anything untill the download is complete in the new window.

```
<input type="button" onclick="mergeFiles()" value="Open all pdf"/>
function mergeFiles() {
                        var newWindow = window.open("CombinedFiles.aspx", "_blank", "width=800,height=500");

                    }
```

**SOLVED:**

EnableSessionState="ReadOnly" fixed my problem.

[Click here for explanation..](https://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/256322-Strangeness-between-ASPNET-AJAX-and-Globalasax/)

Comment: Ever try setting it up as an AJAX request?

Comment: I am not good with AJAX. can you provide an example please.

Comment: http://asp.net-informations.com/ajax/ajax-program.htm is one of dozens of AJAX tutorials out there as it is a pretty broad topic depending on what one is using.

Comment: If you have a long-running process in ASP.NET, it might be better to pass it off to a Windows Service. Or use something designed to help you with it: [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx).